# Looping a request 3 times check values and proceed the function

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, logic

Currently I am facing a logical problem on my code.

What I want to do is to request a site, get the JSON code and check the values. This is working fine and also the if and elif.

But now, I want to check for example the value '99' 3 times before I go for the do_value99() function.

**Like:**
Request1
Value99 [CHECK]
Request2
Value99 [CHECK]
Request3
Value99 [CHECK]
-> 3 times Value99 -> do_value99()

```
response = requests.post('https://example.org', headers=headers, 
    proxies=proxies,data=data)
try:
    value = response.text.split('{"value')[1].split('|')[0]
    if value == "99":
        do_value99()
    elif value == "100":
        do_value100()
except:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Anyone could help me out? I just need to know how the problem could be solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
# get the value
def get_response_value():
    response = requests.post('https://example.org', headers=headers, proxies=proxies, data=data)
    value = response.text.split('{"value')[1].split('|')[0]
    return value

def do_value99():
    pass

value_count = 0

while True:

    if value_count == 3:
        do_value99()
        value_count = 0

    if get_response_value() == "99":
        value_count += 1
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer. I added it and mainly it seems to be good. 

Buuuut there is still one thing missing:
Now it goes like
1
2
3
Value 99 found
---


It stops obvouisly because of the break. What I want is that it is always counting up to 3 found values, posting the value (in my case it should send a webhook on discord when a value change was detected) and then recheck, like:

1
2
3
Value 99 found (webhook)
1
2
3
value 99 found (no webhook)
1
1
2
3
value 100 found (webhook)
.
.

Comment: okay I removed break and reset the count to zero it will now always do_value99 for every third try but didnt get the part that you talk about webhook

Comment: btw I changed the logic as checking for value 3 to upper position

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should check the value from response every 1 sec in infinite loop and if it find same value for 3 times it will call the function and will do the loop again to check value changes from response. If this what you want.

```
i = 0
j = 0
while True:
    response = requests.post('https://example.org', headers=headers, proxies=proxies, data=data)
    value = response.text.split('{"value')[1].split('|')[0]
    if value == "99":
        if i == 3:
            do_value99()
            time.sleep(1)
            i = 0
        else:
            i += 1
            time.sleep(1)
    elif value == "100":
        if j == 3:
            do_value100()
            time.sleep(1)
            j = 0
        else:
            j += 1
            time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works for me - I combined it with @canpoint ones